# Configure center of the status line in tmux

Tags: tmux

I am using tmux on different servers, and like to show the hostname of the current host in a prominent position in the top center.

In the man page, I only found options to set the right- and left-template strings:

```
set -g status-right "<template string>"
set -g status-left "<template string>"
```

Also the window list can be centered:

```
set -g status-justify centre
```

How can I configure a template-string for the center?

Answer (score 3):

Other than by modifying tmux, you cannot do this, since the left/right status positioning is hardcoded, leaving the center (if large enough) for the window list.

This is the relevant chunk in `status.c`:

```
    /* Work out left and right strings. */
    memcpy(&lgc, &stdgc, sizeof lgc);
    left = status_redraw_get_left(c, t, utf8flag, &lgc, &llen);
    memcpy(&rgc, &stdgc, sizeof rgc);
    right = status_redraw_get_right(c, t, utf8flag, &rgc, &rlen);

    /*
     * Figure out how much space we have for the window list. If there
     * isn't enough space, just show a blank status line.
     */
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the source pointer!! I'll leave the question open for a while, in case s/b finds a way to realize this using some workarounds / plugins, or a new tmux version.

Answer (score 1):

Since the question was asked in 2015, the truth seems to have changed. It is now quite easy to achieve the desired result with just a few lines of config:

The important line is the first one:

```
set -g status-right "#[align=absolute-centre] Hello, world! #[align=right]"
set -ga status-right "#{?window_bigger,[#{window_offset_x}#,#{window_offset_y}] ,}\  %d.%m.%y   %H:%M  #{client_user}@#H "
set -g status-right-length 65
```

This will get you something similar to this status bar:

[image: A tmux status bar showing Hello, world in the middle of the screen]

For further information on how to configure tmux, take a look at [the great manpage](https://man.openbsd.org/tmux).